# Application Controllers getting called before custom RememberMeAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, security, authentication, filter

We are trying to implement Spring security in our application. We are extending RememberMeAuthenticationFilter. But trouble is that our application Controllers are getting called before RememberMeAuthenticationFilter. **Is there anyway to force RememberMeAuthenticationFilter to be called before application Controllers?**
Below are my configuaations. In debug mode I could see that FilterChainProxy.VirtualFilterChain has two sets of filters - original filters and additional filters. Original filters has springSecurityFilterChain but it doesn't call custom RememberMeAuthenticationFilter. And additional filters has RememberMeAuthenticationFilter. Controller is getting called via DispatcherServlet at the end of original filters.

Web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security-context.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" create-session="ifRequired" >
<long list of intercept-url here>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>



    <custom-filter ref="rememberMeProcessingFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" />
        <custom-filter ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />


 </http>



<beans:bean id="rememberMeProcessingFilter" class="uk.co.and.dealofday.security.SecurityRememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
</beans:bean> 



<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="uk.co.and.dealofday.security.SecurityUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
    <beans:property name="securityHelper" ref="securityHelper" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: And it should be called because? There is no secured URL (no `<intercept-url />` element) so the filters are never executed.

Comment: There is a long list of intercept-url. I just skipped that part.

  <access-denied-handler ref="exceptionResolver"/>
  

     <intercept-url pattern="/payment/decision/*" access="permitAll" requires-channel="${configurationBean.springSecurityChannel}"/>

     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>

Comment: You didn't mention that at first :). Filters should always execute before servlets (and thus the controllers). If not there is something wrong with your configuration somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

declare custom `remember` filter after custom `authentication` filter

```
<custom-filter ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
<custom-filter ref="rememberMeProcessingFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" />
```